# Выполнение скрипта после получения письма / outlook / VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

```
Sub WorkWithEmails(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim oLookItem As Object
Dim oLookMail As MailItem
Dim oLookFldr As Folder
Dim oLookName As NameSpace
Dim Ret_Val

Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oLookName = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oLookFldr = oLookName.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each oLookItem In oLookFldr.Items
    If TypeOf oLookItem Is MailItem Then
        Debug.Print oLookItem.Subject
        'Debug.Print oLookMail.ReceivedTime
        'Debug.Print oLookMail.Sender
        'Debug.Print oLookMail.SenderEmailAddress
        Debug.Print oLookItem.Body
        Ret_Val = Shell("path\Python37\python.exe " & "path\draft.py" & " -t " & oLookItem.Subject & " -d " & oLookItem.Body)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Этот код завершается ошибкой, потому что если я правильно понял, правило срабатывает раньше (событие), чем письмо появляется в папке.

Я пробовал:

```
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
Sub WorkWithEmails(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

Sleep (5000)
...
```

И

```
...
Sleep (5000)
For Each oLookItem In oLookFldr.Items
```

в этом случае при получении нового письма ничего не происходит.

Если запустить `Sub WorkWithEmails()`, то всё отлично отрабатывает (при условии, что письмо находится в папке).

Так же я пробовал `Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items` и другие вариации строки включающую в себя `WithEvents` встречающиеся на просторах сети.
Если данная строка будет размещена в `Module` даже без запуска:

> Compile Error: Only valid in object module

Если строку поместить в `ThisOutlookSession`, то либо ничего не происходит, либо нет сценариев для выбора в меню Скрипт Правил.

draft.py

```
from datetime import datetime
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-t")  # тема
parser.add_argument("-d")  # описание
args = parser.parse_args()

f = open('path/logs/jira.log', 'a')
f.write(str(datetime.now().strftime('%d%m%y')) + ':' + args.t + ', ' + args.d + '\n')
f.close()
```

**Что я упускаю?**

*требуется выполнить python скрипт передав в него тему и тело письма при поступлении нового входящего письма*

Comment: решение вопроса - https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267757/12785139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private WithEvents myOlItems  As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
      Set olApp = Outlook.Application
      Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
      Set myOlItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim Ret_Val
  
  If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = Item

    'MsgBox Msg.Subject
    'MsgBox Msg.Body
    Ret_Val = Shell("C:\Users\Violet\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe C:\Users\Violet\PycharmProjects\test_bot\draft.py -t """ & Msg.Subject & """ -d """ & Msg.Body & """")
  End If

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

После вставки кода в `ThisOutlookSession` модуль **необходимо перезапустить Outlook**.